# jquery data table action button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Can anyone help me about the best approach to add action button like edit, delete in each row in jquery data table?

I had gone through some links but didn't find a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetStudentGridData", "UserManagement")',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#student-datatable').DataTable({
                data: data,
                aoColumns: [
                    { mData: "FirstName" },
                    { mData: "Class" },
                    { mData: "Roll" },
                    { mData: "PresentAddress" },
                    { mData: "BloodGroup" },
                    { mData: "RegisterDate" },
                    {
                        mRender: function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<a href="@Url.Action("Edit","Users")?id=' + data + '" class="editUser">Edit</a>';
                        }
                    }

                ]

            });
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the js code that I used to render data table. Each row has a student details and in my return 'data' object I had studentID property. I want to fetch data using that studentID when user click Edit button in a row.

Kindly help me about how to render edit and delete button and also how to handle them.

**Solution :**
I have tried a new approach. Instead of rendering column using datatable property I have added button in html

```
<table id="student-datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-highlight table-checkable" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>

        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Class</th>
        <th>Roll</th>
        <th>PresentAddress</th>
        <th>Blood Group</th>
        <th>Register Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    @{
        foreach (var cl in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>@cl.FirstName @cl.LastName</td>
                <td>@cl.Class</td>
                <td>@cl.Roll</td>
                <td>@cl.PresentAddress</td>
                <td>@cl.BloodGroup</td>
                <td>@cl.RegisterDate</td>
                <td>
                    <div >
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default edit-student-btn" data-student-id="@cl.StudentID"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Then I just call the jquery datatable method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#student-datatable').DataTable();
});
```

This give me nice output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have to use `event delegation` for elements added dynamically.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

You should bind click event handler using **.on()** method.

```
$(document).on('click','.editUser',function(){
    var studentID=$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(6).html();
});
```

Comment: And how to render those buttons?

Comment: You mean how to display in the page ?

Comment: yes how to render edit and delete button in each row of table

Comment: @RobinHalder,have a look to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ntcwust8/228/. I make an example in order to show you how to format a row using `columnDefs` and `fnCreatedRow` methods.

Comment: But in your case, the idea is the following: render the `studentID` in the table, then `hide` the column, render the button with `editUser` class like in my example, and the last step is to take the studentID when you click the button, using `closest` method.